# print 1.41069562657e-25 as 1.41*10^-25

Tags: python, math

I have a variable

```
sr = 2*grav*mass/c**2
```

It equates to `1.41069562657e-25` (and prints as such). How do I print it in it's 'normal' form, `(1.41*10^-25)`?

Comment: [That's scientific notation that's recognized as coming from computers or calculators.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Notation#E_notation).  Nothing abnormal about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
>>> sr = 1.41069562657e-25
>>> print("{:.3g}".format(sr).replace("e", "*10^"))
1.41*10^-25
```

However, the `e` notation in computer floating point output is widely understood and accepted.

Comment: I know that the e notation is fine, I just thought python may have had a more standard way to do this. 

This of course works perfectly though. 
Thanks

Comment: @MikeVaughan: Note that this does not use the exponent notation for numbers like 1.23.

Comment: @EOL: Please note that I placed parentheses around the expression to print so that this answer would also apply to Python 3.x. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: @EOL I noticed. That's fine though, the numbers I'll be replacing will always be the same length and format as the example. If they're not, I have  other errors. HahA

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yeah, I should have put your parentheses back when editing. :)  As a side note: I do not encourage Python 2 users to use parentheses with print, because `print(1, 2)` does not give the same result in Python 2 and Python 3, which might be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also first separate mantissa and exponent:

```
import math

def mant_exp(num):
    '''
    Returns the mantissa and (base 10) exponent of num.

    num -- float or int.
    '''

    try:
        exponent = math.floor(math.log10(abs(num)))
    except ValueError:  # Case of log10(0)
        return (0, 0)  # Convention: 0 = 0*10^0
    mantissa = num/10**exponent
    return (mantissa, int(exponent))
```

and then use Python's flexible formatting:

```
>>> sr = 1.41069562657e-25
>>> print '{:.2f}*10^{}'.format(*mant_exp(sr))
1.41*10^-25
```

and get full control over what you print.  You can for example add an optional '+' sign in front of the exponent, etc.

This *always* gives you a scientific notation result, even for numbers like 1.23 (this can be what you want):

```
>>> print '{:.2f}*10^{}'.format(*mant_exp(1.23))
1.23*10^0
```

Greg's answer does not always print in scientific notation (for 1.23, for instance), but it is certainly simpler.

Comment: Have to special-case zero, I think.

Comment: @DSM: True, because there is no unique representation of 0 with the scientific notation. I added 0 as a special case, with a conventional result.

Comment: For what it's worth (not much :-) ) these will also induce some minor fuzz in the results (unless the computer uses base-10 floating point in the first place).  The .replace('e', ...) method in the other answer will retain as much accuracy as possible.  One other possibility is to use the `decimal` module, but that's serious overkill here.